# mongodb C++11 bsoncxx find() member can't return correct result

Tags: mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I have some difficulties calling find() to query document. 
I insert two records to database
[here is the pic of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auzw8.jpg)
`{
       "_id": ObjectId("58f21ae56d79a41a895c9c72"),
       "userID": NumberInt(100),
       "firendId": NumberInt(333),
       "rekey": "333333333333"
    }

    {
       "_id": ObjectId("58f21aae6d79a41a7509942e"),
       "userID": NumberInt(100),
       "firendId": NumberInt(333),
       "rekey": "3333333333333333333333333333333333333342523523532532532532532532523532532432432r32r3243253232rt32453242323r"
}`

here is the c++ code

```
`
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document filter_builder;
filter_builder << "userID" << 100;
auto cursor = collection1.find(filter_builder.view());
for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}`
```

When I run the code, it does not work well. Only return 
   `{
   "_id": ObjectId("58f21ae56d79a41a895c9c72"),
   "userID": NumberInt(100),
   "firendId": NumberInt(333),
   "rekey": "333333333333"
}`
[return result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/danXS.jpg)

Anyone knows how I could do that?
thanks.
I compile with g++ 4.8.4, ubuntu 14.04, mongodb 3.4, c++ driver mongocxx3.1.1

Comment: if I count `cout << distance(begin(cursor), end((cursor)) << endl;` it shows find 1 element.       But if I use `auto cursor = collection1.find({});` the distance is 510.

Comment: How many documents in the collection have a `userID` field of 100? Unless every document has a `userID`of 100, the number of documents returned with a filter of `{}` should be different, since that returns everything in the collection.

Comment: @Saghm Thx, I finally found that I used the wrong way to insert data in the loop